# Are Emacs themes just further initialization files, or are there any restrictions what can be coded in them?

Tags: themes, customization

In other words, are Emacs themes, like the .css files containing style declarations for html visualization are, restricted in what they can specify, or are they more like .js script files able to work on any aspect of html elements are, only a recommended and possible way of separating visual layout and functionality, but can be used for any kind of initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the manual:

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Custom Themes`

> In theory, a theme file can also contain other Lisp forms, which
> would be evaluated when loading the theme, but that is bad form.  To
> protect against loading themes containing malicious code, Emacs displays
> the source file and asks for confirmation from the user before loading
> any non-built-in theme for the first time.  As such, themes are not
> ordinarily byte-compiled, and source files usually take precedence when
> Emacs is looking for a theme to load.

Comment: The text above is from Emacs 28 . In Emacs 27 the text mentions it less explicit:  "> When you first enable a Custom theme, Emacs displays the contents of
the theme file and asks if you really want to load it.  Because loading
a Custom theme can execute arbitrary Lisp code, you should only say yes
if you know that the theme is safe; ". My remark on it: this *does not* happen in case of custom themes copied as root to the themes directory. In other words Emacs don't really check if themes are custom or manipulated.

Comment: If someone has root access in the first place, all bets are off -- Emacs can't protect you against that.  With those permissions, you could mess with *any* of the standard elisp libraries, and Emacs would still happily load them.  Or recompile Emacs with malicious C code.  Or anything you wanted to do.  Sneakily providing a new Emacs theme would be the very least of your concerns.  The word "custom" was certainly never intended to include "files in the Emacs installation which have been modified by the superuser".